# Can I log into ubuntu if I messed up my authorized_keys file?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, putty

I was trying to add another user to log in as and added the new public key into the `authorized_keys` file. It was it's own line underneath the original key for ubuntu (although I'm now thinking I needed a new file entirely?).

I had changed the permissions and ownership of the file and it wasn't working for my new username. It kept giving me "`Server Refused Our Key`".

I was getting fed up and stupidly closed out my active putty session. And now I can't log in as my new user, or as Ubuntu. I feel like I might be out of luck. I've  don't know how to log back in at all now.

Please help!

Comment: Try # ssh-copy-id -i ~/your-certificate.pub user@ip to upload to the keys file, then login with corresponding .pem file.

Comment: But can I do that in putty? Or do I need a shell for that? I'm not that well versed in Linux overall. I know a little bit...but you might need to give me step by step instructions here.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out that I can just do it from one of my other AWS servers on Putty. So I did that. But when I tried it, it gave me this:
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try forcing the use of your password instead of the public key authentication?

E.g.:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@host.com
```

The `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2` syntax is one pubkey per line, so simply adding another public key to the next line shouldn't have broken anything.  See `ssh(1)` and `sshd(8)` man pages (`man 1 ssh` and `man 8 sshd`).

Note that if the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2`, `~/.ssh`, or your home directory is writable by other users, sshd will not allow it to be used.  If when you were adjusting permissions you accidentally added a group or other/world write bit to one of these locations, that could have caused the issue.

Comment: Permission denied (publickey) is all I got.

Comment: If password auth is disabled you will need to get someone to fix the permissions if you aren't able to yourself.